# Is it necessary to cut anus hairs

Tags: men-women, hair

Is it necessary to shave anus hairs and if a person finds difficulty in cutting them after 2-3 times he had already cut them but the skin is causing issues and the hairs are just normal should i leave cutting them?

Answer (score 2):

Removal of anus hair is not part of the Sunan al-Fitrah, but if there are too many hairs then they should be removed, so that they do not get contaminated with any impurity when using the toilet.

Aisha reported that the Prophet (saw) said:

> "Ten practices are part of the Fitrah:
>
> - Trimming the mustache
> - letting the beard grow
> - using the toothstick
> - rinsing the nose
> - trimming the nails
> - washing the finger joints
> - plucking the armpit hairs
> - shaving the pubic hair
> - washing the private parts with water
>
> One of the narrators said: "I have forgotten the tenth; except if it was
>
> - rinsing the mouth

Anus hair are not part of the public hair as per [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pubic-hair):

> **Pubic hair**
>
> the hair that grows above the genitals.

**So it not necessary/natural to shave/remove/cut anus hair unless someone wants to or it irritates them or effects purity.**